# Is there any way to automatize Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I seek a way to automatize my Visual Studio processes like building projects, starting tests, etc. Just like `bat` files for many other things.

Is there any way to do it? Maybe special scripting language or api?

Comment: Do you have your projects in a source control system?

Comment: @ds19 yes. I have a number of solutions and it's terrible to rebuild it manually after each pull request. It's one of reasons because of which I asked this question

Comment: Then you should be able to have a build system linked to source control. See [Require the pull request to build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/git/branch-policies) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call [devenv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) from the command line, and invoke actions and build tasks on projects and solutions.

I used to have batch files for VS 2008 and 2010 ([described](https://devio.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/building-visual-studio-solutions-from-batch-file/) [here](https://devio.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/building-visual-studio-solutions-from-the-command-line/)).